# Why is multiprocessing.pool.map raising a PicklingError (Encoding)?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, multiprocessing

Why does the code below run when using **`threads`** but throw an exception when **`multiprocessing`** is used?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadsPool
import urllib2

urls = [
  'http://www.python.org',
  'http://www.python.org/about/',
  'http://www.python.org/doc/',
  'http://www.python.org/download/']

def use_threads():

    pool = ThreadsPool(4)
    results = pool.map(urllib2.urlopen, urls)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print [len(x.read()) for x in results]

def use_procs():

    p_pool = Pool(4)
    p_results = p_pool.map(urllib2.urlopen, urls)
    p_pool.close()
    p_pool.join()

    print 'using procs instead of threads'
    print [len(x.read()) for x in p_results]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    use_procs()
```

The exception is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pools.py", line 39, in <module>
    use_procs()
  File "pools.py", line 31, in use_procs
    p_results = p_pool.map(urllib2.urlopen, urls)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 250, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 554, in get
    raise self._value
multiprocessing.pool.MaybeEncodingError: Error sending result: '[<addinfourl at 35286624 whose fp = <socket._fileobject object at 0x2198ad0>>]'. Reason: 'PicklingError("Can't pickle <type 'instancemethod'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.instancemethod failed",)'
```

I know there is difference between how processes and threads communicate with each other. Why does `pickle` fail on website content? How can I set the encoding to fix this?

Comment: That error raised because you trying to serialize socket object, which is impossible

Comment: Have an idea what function should I pass to map to get the desired output? (read execution on the object)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem isn't an encoding error, it's because of a pickling error since the result `urllib2.urlopen()` returns is an unpicklable object (a `_ssl._SSLSocket` according to the slightly different reason shown in the error message I get with your code). To get around this you can limit usage of the returned object to the subprocess itself by reading the data after opening the url as shown below. This likely means much more data will need to be passed between processes however.

```
# Added.
def get_data(url):

    soc = urllib2.urlopen(url)
    return soc.read()

def use_procs():

    p_pool = Pool(4)
#    p_results = p_pool.map(urllib2.urlopen, urls)
    p_results = p_pool.map(get_data, urls)
    p_pool.close()
    p_pool.join()

    print 'using procs instead of threads'
#    print [len(x.read()) for x in results]
    print [len(x) for x in p_results]
```

Output:

```
using procs instead of threads
[49062, 41616, 40086, 101224]
```

Answer (score 2):

As i've already mentioned - that error is raised because you tried to pass socket object between processes. You must change script logic into something like this:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import urllib2

urls = [
  'http://www.python.org',
  'http://www.python.org/about/',
  'http://www.python.org/doc/',
  'http://www.python.org/download/'
]

def worker(url):
    return urllib2.urlopen(url).read() # string returned

def use_threads():

    pool = ThreadPool(4)
    results = pool.map(worker, urls)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()

    print([len(x) for x in results])

def use_procs():

    p_pool = Pool(4)
    p_results = p_pool.map(worker, urls)
    p_pool.close()
    p_pool.join()

    print('using procs instead of threads')
    print([len(x) for x in p_results])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    use_procs()
```

By the way: you could do pool factory and pick pool from it instead of duplicating code in `use_threads` and `use_procs`:

```
from multiprocessing.pool import Pool
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool
import urllib2

urls = [
  'http://www.python.org',
  'http://www.python.org/about/',
  'http://www.python.org/doc/',
  'http://www.python.org/download/'
]


def worker(url):
    return urllib2.urlopen(url).read()


def pool_factory(key, n):
    if key == 'proc':
        print('using procs instead of threads')
        return Pool(n)
    else:
        return ThreadPool(n)


def main():

    pool = pool_factory('proc', 4)  # change `proc` to anything for using ThreadPool
    results = pool.map(worker, urls)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    print([len(x) for x in results])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks for the input. You were right about the string returned; I didn't create a factory method because this code is solely for practice, not to be used in other code :-)